# Reindexing 5M items in elastic search through Postman: times out

Tags: json, elasticsearch, reindex

I have around 5 Million items in my index v1. I created a new index v2 with slight changes. 
I am trying to reindex all the items in v1 --> v2.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_reindex?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "source": {
    "index": "twitter"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_twitter"
  }
}
'
```

When I tried this, only 1.6 Million items are re indexed. The operation times out. How do I work around it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `wait_for_completion=false` parameter mentioned in the [reindex docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/docs-reindex.html#_url_parameters_3). It allows you to run the reindex request in the background without your HTTP client being forced to wait and block and potentially time out.